# Using Reference in Security Rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose there are two documents that

```
/orgs/foo
/users/alice
```

and `/users/alice` has a reference-type field `org` which references `/orgs/foo`.

`/orgs/foo` should be accessible when `request.auth.uid == 'alice'`. How can I do that?

I guess it is something like this, but I cannot figure out. In other words, how can I get the ID of the referenced document?

```
function isOrgMember(orgId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.org.__id__ == orgId;
}

match /orgs/{orgId} {
  allow read: isOrgMember(orgId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's been a while since the original question but I've had a similar issue and I hope this could help you or others.

Your condition is: 
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.org.__id__ == orgId;`

But `org` is a reference, which (apparently) means you need to `get` it as well. Try this:
`get(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.org).id == orgId;`